# How to change ui on every api call in react native

Tags: react-native, api, server-side-rendering

> I am building an app in react native and on the edit profile screen when I click on the button to save changes it is successfully updated in API ya but it is not updating data on the screen untill I refresh my app please help me out

here is the code I am working on[image: fetching user details using navigation]

[image: created a array of useState to render all input feilds in map function]

[image: here 2 functions 1 for picking image from gallery and 2 trigger on saving changes]

[image: here I am uploading new image to firebase]

[[image: here i am calling api for updtaing user details]][

[image: here is my component code part1]
[image: here is my component code part2]

[image: here is my component code part3]

Comment: In which screen it should update the data? You are only sending changes to your BE you also need to handle saving changes in your UI.

Comment: what are you getting the response as in handleUpdateUser?

Comment: i am getting user updated data in response as in handleUpdateUser and in current screen which is edit profile screen i want to make visible new values just as instagram app edit profile screen has

Comment: basically I want to display data dynamically on every api call, when user update profile it is updated in backend but not updated dynamically in screen